# What firewall configuration do I need for SFTP to be able to put files on a remote server

Tags: firewall, sftp, putty

I have a situation in production where SFTP (using Putty PSFTP) is working when I connect and list files on a remote server but put and get fail with error **permission denied**.

In my dev environment I can use psftp and filezilla with the same username/password to the same remote server and get/put files as expected.

This leads me to think that somehow the network/firewall is blocking my get/put commands in some way but so far I cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: SFTP uses only one port, the SSH port and that either works or doesn't (it doesn't suffer from the two port problems like classic FTP). Check if you're actually connecting to the same host.

Comment: Add some actual information for us -- the current firewall config, the usernames, directory paths and file listings.

Comment: The firewall is configured by my customer so I have limited knowledge.  He says he opened port 22 and indeed I could not connect before he did and now I can connect.

I connect, change directory to /new and try to upload test.txt.  File listings return the directory expected.  I am sure that I am connecting to the same server.  I cannot provide a username here.

Comment: additional information:  on the production machine the server response is that this version is being used: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6, on the dev client I see SSH-2.0-0.0.

I am confident that I am connecting to the same machine (file listings and uploaded files match).  

Also, the prod environment stores the fingerprint as rsa2 and my dev environment uses dss.

Comment: it was a McAfee firewall running a ssh proxy.  no good!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this was because of a McAfee firewall that had an SSH proxy.  Explains everything.